How to retain days and stop in conditional situation and then keep going?
I am trying to count the duration of medication use. I would like to count days that every outpatient visit if they are not exceed 90 days between every visit.
The med_date is the date of every outpatient visit. I first use lag function to count the days between each visit(variable diff).
And I want to retain them and stop if the diff>90.
Then keep going with another id.
My code would stop if the diff>90, but I have no idea how to keep going
data have;
  input ID $ med_date:yymmdd.;
  format med_date yymmdd10.;
cards;
101 2010-11-22
101 2010-11-23
101 2010-11-30
101 2015-03-08
102 2015-01-11
102 2015-01-15
102 2015-02-01
102 2015-02-15
103 2021-03-17
103 2021-03-26
103 2021-04-08
104 2022-02-05
104 2023-03-16
;


data have1;
set have;
by id;
lag=lag(med_date);
format lag yymmdd10.;
if first.id then
dif=0;
else dif=med_date-lag;
run;

enter image description here
The outcome would just stop in the first diff that>90 and would not keep going with another id

So if we encounter just one dif > 90, then you do not want any more obervations output from that ID, correct? Regardless of whether a dif < 90 follows within the same ID?

Use a conditional if to implicitly output only rows that meet the ifs criteria.
  ...
  if dif < 90 ;
  drop lag ; * probably dont need lag variable in the output ;
run ;

You could also use a data set where= option on the output.
data want(where=(dif<=90) ;
   ...
run ;


My 2 cents. Should be easy to follow.
data want;
   set have;
   by id;

   dif = dif(med_date);

   if first.id then do;
      i = 0; dif = 0;
   end;

   if dif > 90 then i = 1;

   if dif < 90 & i = 0;

   retain i; drop i;
run;

Result:
ID   med_date di f
101  2010-11-22  0
101  2010-11-23  1
101  2010-11-30  7
102  2015-01-11  0
102  2015-01-15  4
102  2015-02-01  17
102  2015-02-15  14
103  2021-03-17  0
103  2021-03-26  9
103  2021-04-08  13
104  2022-02-05  0

